# JAVA : Performance and Memory improvement code comparison from codechef

Tags: java, performance

So today I solved a very simple problem from [Codechef](https://www.codechef.com/problems/INTEST) and I solved the problem using JAVA my answer was accepted. My code was.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


class INTEST {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String input = reader.readLine();
        int n = Integer.parseInt(input.split(" ")[0]);
        long k = Long.parseLong(input.split(" ")[1]);
        int count = 0;
        String element;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            element = reader.readLine();
            if (Long.parseLong(element) % k == 0) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

The onine judge reported

- Running Time : 0.58 Second
- Memory : 1340.5M

So, I looked into some other solutions for the same problem (sorted the solution by time) and I got another solution by the user **indontop**.

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String ...args)throws Exception{

        byte b;
        byte barr[]=new byte[1028];
        int r=0,n=0,k=0;
        while((r=System.in.read())!= ' '){
            n=n*10+r-'0';

        }
        //System.out.println(n);

        while((r=System.in.read())!='\n'){          //change
            k=k*10+r-'0';

        }

        //System.out.println(k);
        //System.in.read();             // remove
        n=0;
        int count=0;
        while((r=System.in.read(barr,0,1028))!=-1){

            for(int i=0;i<barr.length;i++){

                b=barr[i];

                if(b!='\n'){            //change

                    n=n*10+b-'0';                   

                }

                else{

                //  i++;            //remove
                    if(n%k==0)count++;
                    n=0;                                        

                }
            }


        }       
        System.out.println(count);


    }



}
```

the execution time and memory for the above code.

- Running Time : 0.13 Second
- Memory : OM

I wonder how was the user able to achieve this much performance and Memory gain with this very simple problem.

I dont understand the logic behind this code, can anyone help me by explaining this code, and also please explain what is wrong with my code.

Thank You.

Comment: Try replacing your BuferredReader.read line with inputstream.read. it should give you a low memory foot print

Comment: @Sanjeev I will try doing that. Thank You.

Comment: @Sanjeev that's actually bad advice in the long run. Using a `BufferedReader` is the correct approach.

Comment: Your code is fine. The faster code is C-like, and relies on a very fixed format, line ending `\n` (not `\r\n`), only digits. And reading one single byte in a loop is not necessarily everywhere faster. Your code might be faster with `new InputStreamReader(System.in, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)` or using bytes only. But why write ugly code?

Answer (score 1):

## How *indontop* achieved a better memory footprint

Basically, *indontop*'s program reads bytes directly from the input stream, without going through readers or reading lines. The only structure it allocates is a single array of 1028 bytes, and no other objects are created directly.

Your program, on the other hand, reads lines from a `BufferedReader`. Each such line is allocated in memory as a string. But your program is rather short, so it's highly likely that the garbage collector doesn't kick in, hence all those lines that were read are not cleared away from memory.

## What *indontop*'s program does

It reads the input byte by byte and parses the numbers directly from it, without using `Integer.parseInt` or similar methods. The characters `'0'` through `'9'` can be converted to their respective values (0-9) by subtracting `'0'` from each of them. The numbers themselves are parsed by noting that a number like `'123'` can be parsed as `1*10*10 + 2*10 + 3`.

The bottom line is that the user is implementing the very basic algorithm for interpreting numbers without ever having the full string in memory.

## Is *indontop*'s program better than yours?

My answer to this is no. First, his program is not entirely correct: he is reading an array of bytes and is not checking how many bytes were actually read. The last array read can contain bytes from the previous read, which may give wrong output, and it is by sheer luck that this didn't happen when he ran it.

Now, the rest of this is opinion-based:

- Your program is much more readable than his. You have meaningful variable names, he doesn't. You are using well-known methods, he doesn't. Your code is concise, his is verbose and repeats the same code many times.
- He is reinventing the wheel - there are good number parsing methods in Java, no need to rewrite them.
- Reading data byte-by-byte is inefficient as far as system calls are concerned, and improves efficiency only in artificial environments like CodeChef and like sites.

## Runtime efficiency

You really can't tell by looking at one run. Those programs run under a shared server that does lots of other things and there are too many factors that affect performance. Benchmarking is a complicated issue. The numbers you see? Just ignore them.

## Premature Optimization

In real world programs, memory is garbage collected when it's needed. Memory efficiency should be improved only if it's something very obvious (don't allocate an array of 1000000 bytes if you only intend to use 1000 of them), or when the program, when running under real conditions, has memory issues.

This is true for the time efficiency as well, but as I said, it's not even clear if his program is more runtime efficient than yours.

## Is your program good?

Well, not perfect, you are running the split twice, and it would be better to just do it once and store the result in a two-element array. But other than that, it's a good answer to this question.